# FCM Token retrieval failed RST

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm doing a GCM to FCM Migration for my app. But when testing my final code on a device I get the following error in my Logcat and the call to Firebase fails.

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: RST
```

There is no information in the Firebase docs what "RST" means etc..

Who can help me out?

EDIT

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think RST is pointing the *reset* flag for network connections. Does your device have a valid network connection? Have you tried connecting on a different one?

Comment: Hmmm was using my WIFI that has external connection, but let me use 4G instead, just to be sure

Comment: Nope it is still failing, with detailMessage "RST"

Comment: Strange. Do also include your code related FCM. It's hard to tell anything without seeing anything.

Comment: Added some screenshots, the code I call and the response I get back

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/fgvYzvfjNZg/LdSy3NXxEgAJ <- same issue it seems

Comment: it also seems that if I unistall the app and install the app again it works, but this is ofcourse not acceptable for the users

Comment: can you please add your AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had contact with the Firebase Team. It seems to be a bug in the 11.8.0 version. To resolve this issue was to bump the version. I used the latest one at this moment. 15.0.2 for Firebase core and 17.0.0 for Firebase messaging together with the 4.0.1 gms plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Just try using

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

And also add

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder().setGcmSenderId("YOUR_SENDER_ID")
```

before calling the getToken Method.. Hope it helps

Comment: getToken() is for the master token. I need 3 tokens. 1 master, 2 by sender id - third parties. Therefor I must do getToken(SENDER_ID, SCOPE)